# Laravel loginUsingId doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.7

I need to manually login a user in Laravel 5.7 via Auth. Once I run Auth::loginUsingId($userId, true) I then relocate the user to his Account page.

The point of this is for a user coming through a token can be logged in into the website, without adding his credentials again.

I've tried anything I could find online, including moving the Session from MiddlewareGroup to Middleware, checking the Cookie name and some other things that didn't work.

My Controller looks something like this:

```
public function loginExternal(Request $request) {
  $userId = $request->uid;

  Auth::loginUsingId($userId, true);

  redirect()->to('/account')->send();
}
```

and the route for it is pretty simple:

```
Route::get('/oneclick/{token}', 'Auth\AccountController@loginExternal')->middleware('signed')->name('oneclick');
```

I would expect the user to be logged in and taken to his account automatically. Now it just sends me to the login page.

What I noticed is that the loginUsingId() method generates a new session id only in this controller, but in other pages of the website, the website is using a different session, the same one (which should happen).

I need to mention that the user does get loggedin in the LoginExternal method. It just doesn't persist to the account page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make custom middleware for this?

Comment: No.. It's added in a simple Controller. From my understanding it should work..

Answer (score -1):

In controller:

```
public function loginExternal($id) {

  $user = User::find($id);

  if($user){
     \Auth::loginUsingId($id, true);

     return redirect('/account');
  } else {
     return redirect('/')->with('error_message', 'No user found!');
  }

}
```

In route file (web.php)

```
Route::get('/oneclick/{id}', 'Auth\AccountController@loginExternal')->name('oneclick');
```